# Sed passing filenames from Bash, but freezes

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script that is trying to convert a tab-separated file and convert it to a comma-separated file. The following script freezes if I pass in '/tmp/filename.txt':

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 's/      /,/g' $1 > /tmp/csvFile.csv
```

However, the script behaves correctly if I explicitly declare the filename:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 's/      /,/g' /tmp/filename.txt > /tmp/csvFile.csv
```

I need this script to be able to take the filename as a command line argument so that it is reusable. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

My $1 was empty, causing my above problem. I still don't understand why $1 was empty though. Here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function main {
    splitCSV
    cat /tmp/output.txt
}

function splitCSV {
    sed 's/      /,/g' $1 > /tmp/csvFile.csv
    awk -F ',' 'NR > 1 !($2 in facilities) { facilities[$2] } END { for (x in facilities) print x }' /tmp/csvFile.csv > /tmp/output.txt
}

main
```

I assume this is some sort of scope problem?

Comment: Are you sure `$1` is not empty?

Comment: You were right. $1 was empty. But I don't understand _why_ it was empty. I've edited my original post regarding this problem.

Comment: How are you calling the script? And functions have their own arguments. Run this code through http://www.shellcheck.net/ to get suggestions that might fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My $1 was empty, causing my above problem. I still don't understand why $1 was empty though.

Inside a shell function, the positional parameters (`$1`, *etc*.) refer to the function arguments, not the script's command-line arguments.  Likewise, inside a shell function, the shell built-ins that manipulate the positional parameters (e.g. `shift`) manipulate the function's local parameter list, not the overall script's list.

If you want a shell function to see the overall script's positional parameters then you must forward them.  For example,

```
#!/bin/bash

function main {
    # forward the first two function arguments
    splitCSV "$1" "$2"
    cat /tmp/output.txt
}

function splitCSV {
    sed 's/      /,/g' "$1" > /tmp/csvFile.csv
    awk -F ',' 'NR > 1 !($2 in facilities) { facilities[$2] } END { for (x in facilities) print x }' /tmp/csvFile.csv > /tmp/output.txt
}

# forward all the positional parameters, each one as one argument
main "$@"
```

You do need to be a bit careful with quoting, however, in case the parameters contain whitespace or other shell metacharacters.

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much!